# Mounting Linux root fs NFS share on OS X?

Tags: mount, osx, nfs, centos

I am attempting to share the root filesystem (`/`) of a CentOS 6.5 virtual machine to my OS X host system.  While this should be relatively simple process, I'm hitting some kind of wall.

Presently my linux `/etc/exports` contains:

```
/ 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash) 127.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

And I can connect to it, while on the linux system (localhost), via this command:

```
mount localhost:/ /mnt/root     #Where I did `mkdir /mnt/root` first
```

But when I flip on over to OS X and attempt a variety of iterations of mount, I just can't get it to work.

For example, if I issue:

```
sudo mount -t nfs hostname:/ /mnt/centos
```

I'll get a `mount_nfs: can't mount / from hostname onto /mnt/centos: Cennection refused`

Oddly I don't see any entries in any `/var/log` files and so I don't see the error messages associated with this refusal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try temporarily disabling SELinux to confirm that it isn't denying this exposure of your `/` filesystem.

**NOTE:** This is extremely unwise, by the way, and I'd recommend not exposing your root filesystem in this manner!!!

#### Checking SELinux's status & disabling

```
$ getenforce
Enforcing

$ sudo setenforce 
usage:  setenforce [ Enforcing | Permissive | 1 | 0 ]

$ sudo setenforce Permissive
$ getenforce
Permissive
```

If this resolves your issue then you'll need to muck with your root filesystem's context's so that it's allowed to be shared out like so. Again you're working against the protections that have been put in place, and all this extra work to accomplish your goal is telling you this.

Rather than muck with adding all these additional contexts, I'd simply disable SELinux, since you're exposing `/` out.

Again I implore you to re-think what you're trying to do here, rather than just blanket share out everything like this.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that it was a firewall issue rather than `selinux`.  When I started poking around I thought that I'd allowed the client through the firewall, but unfortunately this port was still blocked.  Thanks to your post I started poking in the right places!